# gradient_descentを使用すると必ずエラーになる

Tags: python, python3

deep learningを勉強してまして、下記のコードでgradient_descentを入れて実行すると必ずエラーになってしまいます。
解決策のご教示よろしくお願い致します。

```
def function_2(x):
    return x[0]**2 + x[1]**2

init_x = np.array([-3.0, 4.0])
gradient_descent(function_2, init_x=init_x, lr=0.1, step_num=100)
```

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-4e91f7136fec> in <module>
      5 
      6 init_x = np.array([-3.0, 4.0])
----> 7 gradient_descent(function_2, init_x=init_x, lr=0.1, step_num=100)

NameError: name 'gradient_descent' is not defined
```

Comment: エラーに出ている行番号と実際のコードの対応が取れていないように見えますが、実行時のコードはこれで全部でしょうか？であるなら、エラーに出ている通り gradient_descent の定義がされていないのが原因のように見えます。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
このコードで全部です。
現在、jupyter labを使用してコードを書いてます。

このコードはゼロから作るdeep learning pythonで学ぶディープラーニングの理論と実装の本に記載してあるコードです。

Comment: 問題のコードの前のページ(P107)にgradient_descentが定義されています。cubickさんの指摘どおり、これが必要なのだと思います。

Comment: 定義されてるコードを入力したら、問題なく実装できました。
詳細に教えていただきありがとうございます。